How to change the title of each model in Django admin page

I want to change the title of my models in Django admin page. Should I edit the models.py and how?

Share your model.

Please [edit] the question with a more descriptive title. Currently the title does not make it very clear what the issue is about.

So, in your case the app is named "Countries", so you get that in admin panel.
But here's how you can change it:
First, navigate to the apps.py file in your countries app and make edits to the class like so:
class CountriesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'countries'
    verbose_name = 'Type the title you want here'

Next, head over to your __init__.py file within your app and add the following line:
default_app_config = 'countries.apps.CountriesConfig'

For more details, you can check out this page :)

you need to add the following field in your apps.py file :
verbose_name = 'the custom title'


Hello, this changes the part below it. I tried it before, still thanks

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
